# URL Encode String in Python Flask API?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have made a `REST API` using `Python-Flask`, now the `input` for api_call is supposed to be a `string` and that string needs to have `special characters` included. The problem occurs here is that when I make the request with `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/<your string>`, the browser redirected it as a `Google Search Query` and sometimes it just throw the `Not Found 404` error and this only occurs when I use some special characters in my string like `?`. Is there a way to `encode` the string before calling the api? What I have done is I have made an another program that `urlencode` the string passed and `redirect` it to my api call but that doesn't seem like the correct way to call api.
Here's my API code:

```py
# Importing Libraries
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

# Creating Flask App
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    '''
    index function, to inform user of the API route.
    params: None
    return: None
    '''
    return f"Visit:<br><strong>{request.url}api/(your string)</strong><br>to get the api response"


@app.route('/api/<string:body>')
def sample(body):
    # the code for this function is different and can't be shared but the output works similar
    return jsonify({'length': len(body)})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

As I have mentioned the code for the `sample()` function is different from the original but the output generation is completely similar, the original code is also returning the dictionary which will then be jsonified for response just like the code here. The code for `string_reformat` is:

```py
# Importing Libraries
from urllib.parse import quote

# URL Encoding String
input_string = input()
print(quote(input_string))
```

Comment: can you please share the sample input which did not work?

Comment: sure
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Hi Amit, I am an engineer at abc company, can we have a quick chat?`

Comment: It seems like you are doing the right thing, generally the client/js parse and encode the values.